# New Fact Each Day - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a personal hobby website and would like to give out a new beer style each day of the month. I have tried javascript before but am terrible with it. I was hoping this community could help me. I have an array created up to 31 with a different beer style for each day. However I don't know how I would go about getting the beer style to change every day. I have searched the internet for two days trying to figure this out and I have gone to the point of almost breaking my mouse out of frustration. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And if I left any important information that will help you help me I will be glad to retrieve it for you.

I would like the website to show;

Today's Beer Style Is: "Beer Style"

Here is the javascript:

```
var style = new Array();
style[0] = "Munich Helles";
style[1] = "Robust Porter";
style[2] = "American Wheat Beer";
style[3] = "American Wild Ale";
style[4] = "German Pilsner";
style[5] = "Czech Pilsner";
style[6] = "India Pale Ale";
style[7] = "English Brown Porter";
style[8] = "Kolsch";
style[9] = "Altbier";
style[10] = "Vienna Lager";
style[11] = "Baltic Porter";
style[12] = "Weissbier";
style[13] = "Oatmeal Stout";
style[14] = "Saison";
style[15] = "Belgian Dark Strong Ale";
style[16] = "California Common";
style[17] = "Russian Imperial Stout";
style[18] = "Belgian Dubbel";
style[19] = "Cream Ale";
style[20] = "English Brown Ale";
style[21] = "Doppelbock";
style[22] = "Rauchbier";
style[23] = "Lambic";
style[24] = "Gose";
style[25] = "Gueze";
style[26] = "Marzen";
style[27] = "Scwarzbier";
style[28] = "Pale Ale";
style[29] = "Irish Stout";

document.getElementById("dateBox").innerHTML=style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
```

Below is my HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- The Homebrewery
    Author: Chris Stastny
    Date: October 27th, 2015
    -->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Homebrewery - Homebrewing</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The Homebrewery - Homebrewing">
  <meta name="author" content="Chris Stastny">
  <link href="final.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <script src="beerStyle.js"></script>

</head>
<header>
  <h1> The Homebrewery</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Brew Log</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>
  <h2>Greetings!</h2>

    <div id="dateBox">
        Today Beer Style is: 
    </div>   
  <br>   
  <img src="beer.jpg" alt="beer">

  <p>This website was built to keep people informed about my homebrewing adventures. It will have brewday pictures, videos (possibly) in the future, recipes and general homebrewing information. There is also a newsletter that you can sign up for that will go into more detail about what is going on with my brewing.</p>

  <br>
  <footer>The Homebrewery - Homebrewing - 2015</footer>  
</body> 


</html>
```

Comment: So now get the date https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: That's the problem I am having. I am terrible with JavaScript and don't know where to begin. The whole language is foreign to me.

Comment: @andymccullough - Even if I am using it as the days of the month it should start at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.getUTCDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate) To get the day in terms of it's day in the month. It starts and one so you just need to subtract one, and you can use that value as the index in your array:

```
style[ new Date().getUTCDate() - 1 ];
```

As noted arrays start at index `0`, your array as no such value for that index so you may want to use indexes `0` to `30` rather than `1` to `31`. With your current structure you don't need the `- 1`.

Comment: @andymccullough I'm actually about to point that out in an edit, saying they start at `0` so should go from `0` to `30`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - So I would add that to my js file as is? How would I call that in my HTML file?

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd That will give you the string value you want. You can show it with `alert()`, `console.log()`, `.innerHTML`, etc. For example to alert the value you can do `alert(style[ new Date().getUTCDate() - 1 ])`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - I would like for it to show in a box so I would use .innerHTML(style[new Date().getUTCDate() - 1]) if I change the array to start at 1?

Comment: For that you do assignment, `.innerHTML = ...`. [Here is a small example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40e5852u/2/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - I took a look at the fiddle and added it to my project. I still don't get the beer style on my web page. I will add what my code to the original post. If you wouldn't mind looking at it I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd That's because you are running the JavaScript before the elements are parsed. Add the JavaScript at the end of the `<body>` or at least after `<div id="dateBox">`. Or add a `window.onload = function(){ ... }` around your code.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - I understand what you are saying but don't really know how to go about setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var style = new Array();
style[1] = "Munich Helles";
style[2] = "Robust Porter";
style[3] = "American Wheat Beer";
style[4] = "American Wild Ale";
style[5] = "German Pilsner";
style[7] = "Czech Pilsner";
style[8] = "India Pale Ale";
style[9] = "English Brown Porter";
style[10] = "Kolsch";
style[11] = "Altbier";
style[12] = "Vienna Lager";
style[13] = "Baltic Porter";
style[14] = "Weissbier";
style[15] = "Oatmeal Stout";
style[16] = "Saison";
style[17] = "Belgian Dark Strong Ale";
style[18] = "California Common";
style[19] = "Russian Imperial Stout";
style[20] = "Belgian Dubbel";
style[21] = "Cream Ale";
style[22] = "English Brown Ale";
style[23] = "Doppelbock";
style[24] = "Rauchbier";
style[25] = "Lambic";
style[26] = "Gose";
style[27] = "Gueze";
style[28] = "Marzen";
style[29] = "Scwarzbier";
style[30] = "Pale Ale";
style[31] = "Irish Stout";

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();

stuff = document.getElementById('today');
stuff.innerHTML = style[n]
```

```html
<p id="beer">Today's Beer Style Is:<span id="today"> </span>
</p>
```

> <>